# Windows Phone 8 append to JSON file

Tags: json, windows-phone-8, datareader, storagefile

I'm working on a Windows Phone 8 app. 
I'm having issue appending to my JSON file.
It works fine if I keep the app open but once I close it and come back in it starts back writing from the beginning of the file.

Relevant code:

```
private async void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Create a entry and intialize some values from textbox...
    GasInfoEntries _entry = null;
    _entry = new GasInfoEntries();
    _entry.Gallons = TxtBoxGas.Text;
    _entry.Price = TxtBoxPrice.Text;
    _GasList.Add(_entry);

    //TxtBlockPricePerGallon.Text = (double.Parse(TxtBoxGas.Text) / double.Parse(TxtBoxPrice.Text)).ToString();

    // Serialize our Product class into a string    
    string jsonContents = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_GasList);

    // Get the app data folder and create or open the file we are storing the JSON in.            
    StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    StorageFile textfile = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("gasinfo.json", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists); //if get await operator error add async to class (btnsave)

    //open file
    using (IRandomAccessStream textstream = await textfile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
    {
        //write JSON string
        using (DataWriter textwriter = new DataWriter(textstream))
        //using (DataWriter textwriter = new DataWriter(textstream))
        {
            textwriter.WriteString(jsonContents);
            await textwriter.StoreAsync(); //writes buffer to store
        }
    }
}

private async void btnShow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StorageFolder localfolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    try
    {
        // Getting JSON from file if it exists, or file not found exception if it does not
        StorageFile textfile = await localfolder.GetFileAsync("gasinfo.json");

        using (IRandomAccessStream textstream = await textfile.OpenReadAsync())
        {
            //read text stream
            using (DataReader textreader = new DataReader(textstream))
            {
                //get size ...not sure what for  think check the file size (lenght) then based on next 2 commands waits until its all read
                uint textlength = (uint)textstream.Size;
                await textreader.LoadAsync(textlength);
                //read it
                string jsonContents = textreader.ReadString(textlength);
                // deserialize back to gas info
                _GasList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<GasInfoEntries>>(jsonContents) as List<GasInfoEntries>;

                displayGasInfoEntries();

            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        txtShow.Text = "something went wrong";
    }      
}

private void displayGasInfoEntries()
{
    txtShow.Text = "";
    StringBuilder GasString = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (GasInfoEntries _entry in _GasList)
    {
        GasString.AppendFormat("Gallons: {0} \r\n Price: ${1} \r\n", _entry.Gallons, _entry.Price); // i think /r/n means Return and New line...{0} and {1} calls "variables" in json file
    }
    txtShow.Text = GasString.ToString();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you test your app on a real device? If not: please keep in mind, that every time you close the emulator all settings/data you saved in this emulator and its app are gone. So if you use the emulator: don't close it every time.

Comment: Yes I'm testing on my phone. It looks like once I close and re open the app it starts re-writing from the beginning of the file instead of appending to the end.

Answer (score 1):

Do you call the `btnShow_Click` each time you've started the app? Because otherwise the `_GasList` will be empty; if you now call the `btnSave_Click` all previous made changes will be lost.

So please make sure, that you restore the previously saved json data before you add items to the `_GasList`.

Comment: ok...making progress..i restarted app added data (saved it) closed the app cliked the show button then added more data and it wrote to the end of the file!  ( i won't have the show button in my app - it is for testing) So i guess i need to incorporated the reading of the file first (maybe on initialize?) i'd like to have the data already listed in a history page when the app loads. does that make since.. thanks